# Difference between inherits(x,"data.frame") and "class" %in% class("data.frame")

Tags: r

Are these any different from each other? Assume `x` is defined:

```
inherits(x,"data.frame")

"data.frame" %in% class(x)
```

Also, it need not be `"data.frame"`. It can be something else like `"workflow"`. I just want to know as these seem to do the same thing (i.e. check if `x` is a data frame), but I feel like they might be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is in vectorized class checking, for example if you want to check whether an object belongs to one of a number of different classes. Then `inherits` will return a length-one logical vector, whereas `%in%` returns multiple results (one for each test class)

```r
df  <- data.frame(a = 1:3)

inherits(df, c("data.frame", "foo"))
#> [1] TRUE

c("data.frame", "foo") %in% class(df)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

This could be relevant when using a logical test of class type. For example, suppose I want to check that `df` is either a data frame *or* of class `foo`. I can safely put `inherits` inside an `if` statement:

```r
if(inherits(df, c("data.frame", "foo"))) {
  cat("Object df is either a data frame or a foo")
}
#> Object df is either a data frame or a foo
```

But I will get an error if I do the same thing with `%in%`

```
if(c("data.frame", "foo") %in% class(df)) {
  cat("Object df is either a data frame or a foo")
}
#> Error in if (c("data.frame", "foo") %in% class(df)) {
#> : the condition has length > 1
```

If you only want to check for a single class, the two are essentially equivalent, or in the case of tests for multiple classes, wrapping the `%in%` with `any` will achieve the same effect.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>